# edit several field simultaneously in one table in Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have table:

```
id | cat_id | name
1  | 1      | aaa
2  | 1      | bbb
3  | 2      | ccc
4  | 3      | ddd
5  | 2      | eee
6  | 1      | fff
```

I can go to `site.com/table/edit/id/1`
and show me input

```
name (id 1) [ aaa    ] (i hide other field)
```

and I can edit id 1. how can I make something:

`site.com/table/edit/cat_id/1`
and show me:

```
name (id1) [  aaa   ]
name (id2) [ bbb    ] 
name (id6) [ fff    ]
```

and i can edit them, and save. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to achieve this with the default generated forms. But it's quite easy to create your own form (just extends from `sfForm` and implement the `setup()` function). Then add your own logic in the `save()` function.

Pseudo-code:

```
class myForm extends sfForm {
  public function setup() {
    $models = //;

    foreach($models as $model) {
       $this->addWidget(new sfWidgetFormInputText());
       $this->addValidator(new sfValidatorString());
    }
  }

  public function save() {
    // loop through the widgets and save if valid.
  }
}
```

EDIT: Hmm... i think you could also create one form, and add all the edit forms as subforms.

Comment: how can i make this? i can create own form

Comment: thanks, but this $this->addWidget(new sfWidgetFormInputText());
generated same widget. what i must write in $models? query for my table "TableTable.class"?

Comment: i would like edit all field with cat_id = for example 1, 2 etc.

Comment: Do you understand what the foreach loop does? It creates an input (textfield) for every "thing" you want to edit. So $models should be populated with the 'categories', if I understand you correctly.